# Can not connect to internet after upgrade to UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, internet

I checked other answers but are not sure.Hereby some output

```
~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com


~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.112.128.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.112.128.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/network/interfaces and see if your config is OK. (you can edit with "vi")
1) Good IP
2) Good SubnetMask
3) Good Gateway
4) Good dsn-nameservers.

If you're not sure, copy and paste your config.